# Join two ISMV files

Tags: join, ffmpeg, video-streaming, codec

I am currently working on a project involving some task with ismv and ismc files. First of all let me give a brief explanation for the current situation. We are using windows based products only. We are getting some ismv and ismc video files from standard CCTV server. The ouput is only ismv in beggning but after indexing we get ismc file too. For each one hour long stream we are getting one ismv file and one ismc file.

What i need to do now is figure out a way to join multiple one hour streams. For example having a four hour long video will consist of 4 ismv video files.So far I tried ffmpeg codec, but without any success. The same goes for mp4split.

The error for ffmpeg is the following : 
Could not find codec parameters for
 stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 586x480, 500 kb/s): unspecifie
d pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[concat @ 000000000436bd60]

Executed with the following command : 
ffmpeg.exe -f concat -i F.txt -c copy output

Here is the codec of the video taken with Media Info : http://tinypic.com/r/ff0h8z/8

I did not manage to find a version of mp4split to use. Can you please help me solve this problem ?

The final result should be one video only. This video should be a join between the videos given as input. 
ERROR LOG :

```
cmd : >> 
ffmpeg.exe -f concat -i F.txt -c copy output.ismv >> c:\test.log
ffmpeg version N-67586-g3e1ac10 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov 12 2014 22:10:14 with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --
enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-lib
modplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrw
b --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinge
r --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --en
able-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis
 --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-
libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 11.100 / 54. 11.100
  libavcodec     56. 12.100 / 56. 12.100
  libavformat    56. 12.103 / 56. 12.103
  libavdevice    56.  2.100 / 56.  2.100
  libavfilter     5.  2.103 /  5.  2.103
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -729776398
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -1586392803
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -201009241
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 1525559282
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -1669219084
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -1691392434
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 1990351320
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -634604097
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 1469591056
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -1438535317
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 1449123893
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 1691583710
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -351019013
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 309254841
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 473575423
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -1179057153
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -1745148207
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -1161919613
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -1424567262
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -1671905020
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -276201527
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 2129258231
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -1382747181
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -53947666
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -494363989
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 675772942
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 1778317799
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -1694646357
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 322181480
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -129268567
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 161790146
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -182677717
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -1764646342
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 43163370
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -1896031063
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 1945651533
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -1279624828
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -789496900
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 1843265261
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -159919440
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -782702414
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -340957996
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 301061149
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -433378048
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 510092259
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -539818905
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -211670405
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -1489865369
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 1093843445
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -911953424
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 405867055
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 1506095107
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 1756726661
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -1252304115
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -956720060
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 1972752503
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 22752285
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 148807245
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 1593789403
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 341071185
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -1209592176
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -1045063878
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 1595886078
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 1454822618
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 1202334437
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 853741989
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 562229559
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -1846206258
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -949647435
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 2035288695
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -1153464594
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 1586433152
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 204824048
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -68386554
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -1052945868
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -232379875
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -769469796
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 1476243902
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 944865348
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 680117868
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -416140149
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 1156708360
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -264356271
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -1709052362
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -1592065758
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 737752675
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 2064970227
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 27608298
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 1489266222
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 946041170
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 1999898747
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -1002118094
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 881674828
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -1170312534
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 991631349
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -1218616840
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 916839245
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 2133503346
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -2041791480
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -1857022891
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 1901147878
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 594072630
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 580451068
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 1595477547
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 1755470860
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 22914809
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 861184964
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 538973456
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -354806072
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -540053632
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -327661798
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 1232758622
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 2099868463
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -866724819
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -291115259
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 1748168392
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 2019118774
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -928523944
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 1292590826
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -1183926090
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -24524382
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 901119803
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 1866763900
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size 838469106
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] AVC: nal size -388249262
[h264 @ 0000000004417f80] no frame!
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000000000441ce80] decoding for stream 0 failed
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000000000441ce80] Could not find codec parameters for
 stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 586x480, 500 kb/s): unspecifie
d pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[concat @ 000000000441bd60] Impossible to open 'C:\Segment059\CCameraStream.ismv'
F.txt: Operation not permitted
```

The F.txt file contains :

```
file 'C:\Segment059\CameraStream.ismv'
file 'C:\Segment060\CameraStream.ismv'
```

Reference for the approach : https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#samecodec

Comment: mp4split is now commercial, I think. Can you please show the full, uncut command line output from ffmpeg?

Comment: The command I use in cmd is : 
<pre>  fmpeg.exe -f concat -i F.txt -c copy output.ismv <code>

the output is presented here : 
http://tinypic.com/r/2qaslyc/8

mp4Split is commercial. You are right about about that.

Comment: The cmd command is : ffmpeg.exe -f concat -i F.txt -c copy output.ismv

Comment: Please show the **full** output, not just a screenshot. Can you copy-paste  it into your question? I'm not sure if ffmpeg can even concat ISMV files that easily, or if they can be concatenated this way... a sample would be good.

Comment: It is done. Thanks for the effort @slhck